# Spring binding and form field naming

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following beans:

```
class User {
    private List<Address> addresses;

    // ... getter and setter for addresses follows
}

class Address {
    private String street, city;

    // ... getters and setters follows 
}
```

This is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/doSomething" })
public String doSomething(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    // ...
}
```

And the form could be something like

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="addresses[].street" />
    <input type="text" name="addresses[].city" />
    ...
</form>
```

But I get the following error

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'addresses[]' of bean class [User]: Invalid index in property path 'addresses[]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:989) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
```

How should I name the fields in a form so that Spring will be able to do the binding?

Comment: try adding in the controller method: model.addAttribute("retrievedAddresses",user.addresses);                    and then in the form just do:                                                                 name="retrievedAddresses[0]"

Comment: are you using ngRepeat to loop through those addresses? e.g. `<div ng-repeat="address in user.addresses"> .... input fields ... </div>`? If so, you'd need to use address.street etc. The error I think is because it can't convert [""] into [number] and thus it can't locate what element from that array it should access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The problem is that the property is missing an index. Spring can bind multiple properties (collection, lists, arrays) to request parameters, but the names must include an index.

So the form must be

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="addresses[0].street" />
    <input type="text" name="addresses[0].city" />

    <input type="text" name="addresses[1].street" />
    <input type="text" name="addresses[1].city" />
    ...
</form>
```

Instead of `0`, `1` ... you can use `${iterationStatus.index}` in Thymeleaf (server side) or `{{$index}}` in Angular (client side).

Answer (score 0):

The error I think is because it can't convert [""] into [number] and thus it can't locate what element from that array it should access.

For collections you either use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop through or use explicit indexes. In most cases you'll want to loop, so here's an example of that:

```
<form ng-repeat="address in user.addresses">
    <input type="text" ng-model="address.street" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="address.city" />
    ...
</form>
```

Note that this works if you submit the form using angular (thus, rather than allowing for the standard HTML submit, you submit the scope object that Angular is modifying due to the ng-model mapping.

Comment: This way no parameter is submitted, so Spring will not do any binding.

Comment: If you're submitting the form from Angular, the binding should be there. If you're using the standard HTML submit, I'm not sure how you'd do it.